# What's the preferred way to cache .NET objects in SP Foundation?

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, caching, object-cache

I have a SharePoint 2010 Founation (farm) solution scoped at the site collection level. What I'd like to do is cache some of my custom .NET objects so that the page requests can be processed faster. What's the preferred way to do this?

I've already read about the standard caching mechanisms in SharePoint (BLOB-Cache, Output-Cache and Object-Cache) but they are only availible in the SharePoint Server Edition.

Any helpful hints or links would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint Foundation does not support output caching. You have to rely on ASP.NET Cache objects in your code.

Infact BLOB cache, page output, and object cache are not available in SharePoint foundation. Page output and object cache require that you activate the ‘SharePoint Server Publishing’ feature located in the site features of your web site, so these will not be available to you if you are using SharePoint Foundation.

Here is the official resource: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770229.aspx#BLOB

Comment: Hi Falak, can you specify any official sources that mention BLOB caching can be in SP Foundation? I've come across an number of sites that say that it's only availible in the Server Edition.

Comment: Hi Robert, I intend to meant the Remote Blob Storage which is available in SP Foundation. RBS is a way to store large files outside of the content database in a way that is seamless to SharePoint. While Blob Caching is IIS's way of storing frequently accessed files locally so it does not have to keep reaching out to the database to let them load quicker in the browser. So, both concepts are different but can be used at the same time. I have just updated my response. Sorry for misleading response earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In my webparts and other SP related items, I typically will use the HttpRuntime.Cache for my caching needs.